# Next/previous a-like single navigation

Tags: menus, navigation

I have on the [site](http://portraitvessels.com/) navigation menu which uses next/previous functionality to navigate through the site. Currently it is a hard coded image map with related links on each page.

I know how to get  next/previous functionality from breadcrumbs to work for sub-pages following code from [here](http://www.qualitytuts.com/wordpress-custom-breadcrumbs-without-plugin/) , but I have no idea how to get that functionality to work between parent (top) menus, when there is no sub-pages or to jump to next parent (top) menu when landing page is a last sub-page.

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably, you wish for the next/previous links to move the user through the site according to the order of the items in the navigation menu. I don't think you should be looking at breadcrumbs NOR WordPress's prev/next links (which will navigate items according to the order they appear in the query). Were I you, I would parse `nav_menu_item`s to determine the next and previous items. The way I see it, this question has absolutely nothing to do with breadcrumbs...

Comment: I have used next/previous functionality from mentioned breadcrumbs to get similar functionality. I will reconsider your suggestion as another solution. BTW - if there are posts I need to have them present in the `nav_menu_items` to navigate through them? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research it looks like it will require to use two separate methods to get next/previous page/post to work.

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856144/adding-next-and-previous-buttons-to-static-pages-in-wordpress),[here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links#The_Next_and_Previous_Pages) and [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/next-page/)

Solution for pages:

```
    <?php
$pagelist = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=asc');
$pages = array();
foreach ($pagelist as $page) {
   $pages[] += $page->ID;
}

$current = array_search(get_the_ID(), $pages);
$prevID = $pages[$current-1];
$nextID = $pages[$current+1];
?>

<div class="navigation">
<?php if (!empty($prevID)) { ?>
<div class="alignleft">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prevID); ?>"><img src="arrow-left.png"></a>
</div>
<?php }
if (!empty($nextID)) { ?>
<div class="alignright">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextID); ?>"><img src="arrow-right.png"></a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div><!-- .navigation -->
```

solution for posts

```
<?php previous_post(' %', '<img src="arrow-left.png" alt="Next" border="0" align="right" />', 'no'); ?>
<?php next_post(' %', '<img src="arrow-right.png" alt="Next" border="0" align="right" />', 'no'); ?>
```